# How do I append multiple criteria in elastic search URI?

Tags: list, http, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I don't have the possibility of sending a body request, so I have to concatenate the criteria in the main URI. Right now I have something like: server:port/index/_search?size=10, for a pagination with the size of 10, I need to add the "from" criteria also, but nothing I've tried works: / or , .

Answer (score 1):

Correct format would be `http://localhost:9200/<your-index>/_search?from=10&size=20`,

You need to add `size` with the separation of `&`.